# Jquery list item in template hide/show on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a to do list and on each list item when is clicked I need it to open buttons for edit, complete and delete... How to do it for every one separately? here is my code

**Jquery :**

```
$('.editBt').hide();

$('').click(function(){
    $('.editBt').toggle();
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    {{#each tasksToDo}}
        {{>task}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>

<template name="task">
    <li class="list_item">
        <span id="editingTask">{{> editableText collection="tasks" field="title"}}</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
        <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</li>
```

It show's and hide on every list item I have. I know this is because of class but how to do it for just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to refer to the current item clicked, then find the `.editBt` div related to it using `find()` function and finally toggle it using `toggle()` function :

```
$('.list_item').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.editBt').toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$('.editBt').hide();

$('.list_item').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.editBt').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">editableText 1</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
      <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">editableText 2</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
      <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">editableText 3</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
      <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </li>
    <li class="list_item">
    <span id="editingTask">editableText 4</span>
    <br>
    <div class="editBt">
      <button class="completed">Completed</button><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this, which hides just the buttons on load and toggles them on click:

```
$('.editBt').hide();

$('.list_item').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.editBt').slideToggle();
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pn7gnrm1/)**

If this isn't correct, please edit your question to clarify which elements should be clicked and which should toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.editBt').toggle();
```

use 'this' to target the clicked element:

```
$(this).toggle();
```